# image not found error come when i try to update tiltle and description field only in mern stack with cloudinary

Tags: database, image, http-status-code-404, mern, cloudinary

i got this error : error in blog post: {

message: 'Resource not found - [https://res.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/image/upload/v1700847934/blog-mern-app/kzg1lxdqfnt2asls0mgq.jpg'](https://res.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/image/upload/v1700847934/blog-mern-app/kzg1lxdqfnt2asls0mgq.jpg%27),

name: 'Error',

http_code: 404

}

**this is my create post controller:**

const createPostController = async (req, res) => {

```
try {

    const { title, description, image } = req.body;

    if(!title){

        return res.status(400).json({message:"invalid title"});

    }

    if(!description){

        return res.status(400).json({message:"invalid description"});

    }

    if(!image){

        return res.status(400).json({message:"invalid image"});

    }

    const uploadPhoto = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(image, { folder: "blog-mern-app" });

    const createPost = new Post({ title, description, image: { public_id: uploadPhoto.public_id, url: uploadPhoto.secure_url } });

    await createPost.save();

    res.status(201).json({success:true, message:"post created successully", createPost});

} catch (error) {

    res.status(500).json({success:false, message: "Error Creating The Blog post"})

}
```

}

**this is my update post controller**

const updatePostController = async (req, res) => {

```
try {

    const { title, description, image } = req.body;

    const currentPost = await Post.findById(req.params.id);



    if (!currentPost) {

        return res.status(404).json({ message: "Post not found" });

    }



    if(!image){

        return res.status(404).json({message:"image is compulsary"});

    }



    if (image) {

        if (currentPost.image) {

            const currentImgId = currentPost.image.public_id;

            await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(currentImgId);

        }

       

        const uploadNewImg = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(image, { folder: "blog-mern-app" });

        currentPost.image = {public_id:uploadNewImg.public_id, url:uploadNewImg.secure_url};

    }

    currentPost.title = title;

    currentPost.description = description;



    await currentPost.save();

    res.status(201).json({ success:true, message:"updated post successfully", currentPost});

} catch (error) {

    console.error("error in blog post:", error);

    res.status(500).json({success:false, message: "error in updating blog post", error:error.message });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to confirm if the asset `blog-mern-app/kzg1lxdqfnt2asls0mgq` is in your Media Library? Most likely it is not uploaded successfully. There are chances where the asset may have been deleted or uploaded with a different public_id.

If you weren't able to find the root cause, I suggest that you raise this with Cloudinary support for them to take a look at what really happened to your asset.

https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: thanks john for the suggestion . i will try